# How to Create a Query Activity in Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, navigation

I'm trying to follow the documentation on [How to Create a Query Activity](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/query_activity/) but the first step eludes me.

1. Click the **Interactions** tab on the navigation bar

Where can I find interactions? This is the navigation bar I am presented with when I log in and I can't find interactions in any other submenus.

[image: Navigation]

Am I missing some permissions? Is there more useful documentation? Most of the video tutorials I have found for Exacttarget/Marketing Cloud are out of date and the navigation has changed substantially.

Comment: you need to go into Email Studio. Inside of the email studio navigation is the interactions tab

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This functionality has since moved into **Automation Studio**.

Hover over the `Journey Builder` tab -> Click on `Automation Studio`

- Hover over `Journey Builder` tab
- Click on `Automation Studio`
- Click `Activities` tab at the top

This will take you into the Activities screen where you can manage your activities.

- Click `Create Activity` in the top right corner

This is where you'll be able to enter the details for you activity, create and validate your desired SQL query, and specify the target data extension.