# How to Create a Query in Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, activity, interaction

I am having a similar issue to this question ([How to Create a Query Activity in Marketing Cloud](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/138920/how-to-create-a-query-activity-in-marketing-cloud)), except I have found Email Studio -> Interactions, but I have no option to select "Query" from the drop down.

I've double checked that I have permissions, and even asked Admin level users if they can see it, and they cannot.

So, how do you actually get to the Query editor? Are there other permissions needed? I've got Query checked in the Roles area.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've noticed in most newer accounts the SF team will exclude adding certain interactions into Email Studio. A support member informed me that there is a default rule in their system that will have certain interactions excluded from Email Studio once they are activated in Automation Studio - but this can be changed.

Summary: You should be able to access queries within Automation Studio under the **Activities** tab, but you can also ask support to enable all interactions within Email Studio so that you can access them there too.

Comment: This was it, thanks! I found Query under Automation Studio > Activities.